# Maven project and Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven, workspace

I have been working with Netbeans quite a while and I am now moving to Eclipse.

Basically I have a Maven project that I would like to work on using Eclipse.

What I am not sure about is whether I need to point my Eclipse workspace to the directory where my project super pom is located or whether the Eclipse workspace needs to point to a clean/empty directory.

My question is basically:

- **Are the source files eventually located in the Eclipse workspace directory?**

Can anyone please advise?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the m2e or m2eclipse plugin installed, you can just do "Import..." then "Existing Maven Projects" and point it at the super-pom. It'll import all the modules it finds, as separate projects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Eventually are the source files located in the workspace directory?

Comment: No, they stay where they are. But if you check out into your workspace directory, you can then 'import' them, even though they're already physically in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the maven eclipse target to generate project files so you can  move them directly in the eclipse workspace:

mvn eclipse:eclipse

[info on the plugin](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of personal preference whether you have the source files in the workspace folder or not. Eclipse can import your project from any folder. Personnaly, I keep my projects folder separated from the workspace folder.